# How to generate random numbers faster in R?

Tags: r, optimization, random

My project requires generating a substantial amount (in the order of 10^7, for example) of random numbers that is normally distributed, and this step takes a significant amount of computational resources.

Is there a more efficient method than `rnorm` for generating such data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Ziggurat method via [RcppZiggurat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppZiggurat).  This is one of the faster/fastest algorithm for standard normally distributed random numbers.

The [pdf vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppZiggurat/vignettes/RcppZiggurat.pdf) has  timing comparison charts; there is also one on [package page on my server](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.ziggurat.html).